# Android Beam failed when the length of transferring data is out of range

Tags: android, push, nfc, android-beam

I just implemented an Android Beam project to transfer text data from Nexus S to a NFC card reader, by using the callback CreateNdefMessageCallback and creating the NdefMessage in createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) method.
Everything is OK at first, but I found that if the length of the text to transfer is more than 42 byte(don't include the NDEF head), it failed to push the data. Although I tapped the screen many times, there is no response.
I also tried to chunk the NDEF Records, but the SDK suggested that "Applications should not attempt to manually chunk NDEF Records ".
Does anyone meet the same issue?
It would be very thankful to get your suggestion.
thank you!

Comment: So maybe you are hitting an 64-byte limit on message size?

Comment: Can you post code from the NFC card reader side? That my be helpful to understand what is going in.

Answer (score 1):

I have already sent NDef Messages between 2 Android devices (several Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S, 4.0.1, 4.0.2 and 4.0.3) with 32000 Bytes + NDef Header. If you are really careful (don't move the devices) and patient (it lasts a few minutes) it can be done withou any problem.

So, the problem should not be on the Android part - but I did not test it with a card reader.